Uniform density over 2 segments
Background
Let $V_1, V_2 \in \mathbb{R}^2$ be the vertices of a segment and let $z$ be uniformly distributed over that segment. Now consider the random vector
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
y&=z+v\\
v&\sim \mathcal{N}(0,R)
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
if $z$ and $v$ are independent then we can write the PDF of $y$ as the convolution
\begin{equation}
p(y)=\int p_z(z)\,\mathcal{N}(y-z;0,R)\,\mathrm{d}z
\end{equation}
where the PDF of $z$ is $p_z(z)=\frac{1_c(z)}{\mathrm{lenght}(c)} =\frac{1_c(z)}{\lVert V_2-V_1\rVert}$, with $1_c(z)$ be the characteristic function that gets unitary value over the segment $c=(V_2,V_1)$ and zero outside. Thus, $p(y)$ can be written in the form
\begin{equation}
p(y)=\frac{1}{\lVert V_2-V_1 \rVert}\int 1_c(z)\,\mathcal{N}(y-z;0,R)\,\mathrm{d}z
\end{equation}
Interestingly, $p(y)$ admits a closed expression. To get the result, we write $z$ in the following form
\begin{equation*}
z(u)= (V_2-V_1)u + V_1  
\end{equation*}
so that, if $\dot{z}(u)\triangleq \frac{\mathrm{d}z}{\mathrm{d}u}=V_2-V_1$,
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
p(y)&=\frac{1}{\lVert V_2-V_1\rVert}\int 1_c(z(u)) \,\mathcal{N}(y-z(u); 0, R)\,\lVert \dot{z}(u)\rVert \mathrm{d}u\\
&=\frac{1}{\lVert V_2-V_1\rVert}\int 1_{[0,1]}(u)\,\mathcal{N}(y-z(u); 0, R)\,\lVert V_2-V_1\rVert\mathrm{d}u\\
&\stackrel{*}{=}\int 1_{[0,1]}(u)\,\mathcal{N}(y-z(u); 0, R) \,\mathrm{d}u\\
&=\int_0^1 \mathcal{N}(y-z(u); 0, R) \,\mathrm{d}u
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
then, after some algebraic gymmnastic involving a square completition, the integral can be solved in terms of the standard CDF plus a bunch of scaling factors.
I would like to point out a fact, since I'm not 100% sure about that. If I'm not wrong, $(*)$ tells that $z=(V_2-V_1)u+V_1$ with $u\sim\mathcal{U}([0,1])$ gives $z$ uniformly distributed over the segment $c=(V_1,V_2)$. This because we have the following equality
\begin{equation*}
\int p_z(z)\,\mathcal{N}(y-z;0,R)\,\mathrm{d}z=\int 1_{[0,1]}(u)\,\mathcal{N}(y-z(u);0,R)\,\mathrm{d}u
\end{equation*}
from which we deduct that $z\sim p_z(z)$ is equivalent to $z(u)$ with $u\sim p_u(u) =1_{[0,1]}(u)=\mathcal{U}([0,1])$.
Problem definition
Let $V_1,V_2,V_3$ be three vertices of a polygonal line with two edges $(V_1,V_2)$ and $(V_2,V_3)$. I would like to repeat the previous exercise in the slighlty more complex setting where $z$ is uniformly distributed over the polyogonal line $c(V_1,V_2,V_3)$.
Since we are just considering the union of two segments, I think that we can obtain a closed expression for $y$ also for this case (and then, also for a polygonal line with $n$ edges).
Thus, I'm searching for the closed expression of $p(y)$ when $z$ is uniformly distributed over the line $c(V_1,V_2,V_3)$.
What I've done
Following the suggestions provided by the previous solution, the main problem is to parametrize $z$ in function of a suitable scalar random variable $u$. A first naive attempt is to consider
\begin{equation}
\tag{$1$}
z=\begin{cases}
\hfil (V_2-V_1)\{2u\}+V_1 \hfil & \text{if } u\in[0,1/2)\\
\hfil (V_3-V_2)\{2u\}+V_2 \hfil & \text{if } u\in[1/2, 1]\\
\end{cases} \\
\end{equation}
where $\{x\}\triangleq x-\lfloor x\rfloor$ is the fractional part function and
\begin{equation*}
u\sim \mathcal{U}([0,1])
\end{equation*}
but this works properly only when $\lVert V_2-V_1\rVert=\lVert V_3-V_2\rVert$. Indeed, the current parametrization tends to concentrate more points over the shortest edge. To solve this problem, we must assign to each edge a probability mass that is proportional to its length. To achieve this goal, I've found this distribution
\begin{equation}
\tag{$2$}
u\sim p_u(u)\triangleq \frac{2}{\lVert V_2-V_1 \rVert + \lVert V_3-V_2 \rVert}\begin{cases} 
\lVert V_2-V_1 \rVert & \text{if } u \in[0,1/2)\\
\lVert V_3-V_2 \rVert & \text{if } u \in[1/2,1]\\
\hfil 0 \hfil & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
which seems to generate an uniform sample over the line $c=(V_1,V_2,V_3)$ even when $\lVert V_2-V_1\rVert \neq \lVert V_3-V_2\rVert$.
To convince myself, I use my not bullet-proof method that I used previously to show that $z(u)=(V_2-V_1)u+V_1$ is uniformly distributed over $c=(V_1,V_2)$ if $u\sim\mathcal{U}([0,1])$. Starting from the fact that
\begin{equation*}
\dot{z}(u)=\begin{cases}
\hfil 2(V_2-V_1) & \text{if } u\in[0,1/2)\\
\hfil 2(V_3-V_2) & \text{if } u\in[1/2,1]
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}
it follows
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
p(y)&=\int p_z(z)\,\mathcal{N}(y-z;0, R)\,\mathrm{d}u \\
&= \frac{1}{\mathrm{length}(c)}\int 1_c(z)\,\mathcal{N}(y-z;0,R)\,\mathrm{d}z\\
&=\frac{1}{\lVert V_2-V_1\rVert+\lVert V_3-V_2\rVert} \int 1_c(z)\,\mathcal{N}(y-z;0,R)\,\mathrm{d}z\\
&=\frac{1}{\lVert V_2-V_1\rVert+\lVert V_3-V_2\rVert} \int 1_c(z(u))\,\mathcal{N}(y-z(u);0,R)\,\lVert \dot{z}(u)\rVert\,\mathrm{d}u\\
&=\frac{1}{\lVert V_2-V_1\rVert+\lVert V_3-V_2\rVert}\left[\int_0^{1/2}\mathcal{N}(y-z(u);0, R) \lVert 2(V_2-V_1) \rVert\, \mathrm{d}u\right]\\
&\qquad+\frac{1}{\lVert V_2-V_1\rVert+\lVert V_3-V_2\rVert}\left[\int_{1/2}^{1}\mathcal{N}(y-z(u);0, R) \lVert 2(V_3-V_2) \rVert\, \mathrm{d}u\right]\\
&=\int p_u(u)\,\mathcal{N}(y-z(u); 0, R)\,\mathrm{d}u
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
which tells that $z\sim p_z(z)$ is equivalent to $z(u)$ with $u\sim p_u(u)$, where the former is given by $(1)$ and the latter by $(2)$.
Now the problem is to solve the integral in $\mathrm{d}u$, but this is a story for a new post if it turns out that I'm not able to figure out by myself how to solve such integral.
Questions
In these kind of problems we have to deal with "pathological" change of variables, where we map double integrals in line integrals (loosing a degree of freedom). Since I don't feel confortable with these problems, I'm searching for an external opinion about my derivations. I have two questions.

How do we prove that $(1)$ and $(2)$ gives a point $z$ uniformly distributed over $c=(V_1,V_2,V_3)$? Is my proof correct?
Is it true that $p(y)=\int p_u(u)\,\mathcal{N}(y-z(u); 0, R)\,\mathrm{d}u$?


Whenever I encounter a question that is prefaced with many screens of mathematical equations, I ask myself "do I really want to read this?"  The answer almost always is no--and I suspect most other readers react the same way.  If you're serious about getting help, the solution is to (a) motivate and summarize your question at the outset and (b) present one of the simplest possible examples of the phenomenon of interest.

BTW, as far as I can tell you are asking how to express the density of a mixture of two distributions in terms of their densities.  After all, a uniform distribution over a union of two segments is a mixture of the uniform distributions on those segments (weighted by the segment lengths).

I am having a hard time understanding this problem (see @whuber's comments above). An obvious change of variable would be to add the lengths of the two segments together and treat the location of $z$ as uniformly distributed over this length. You would then be back in the single-line segment case.   This clearly can be extended to any number of line segments.  The inverse mapping should be clear as well.  What am I not understanding?

@ whuber, thanks for the tips. I'll keep them in mind for my next questions.
@ jbowman, I'm attempting to rephrase the question: Is it true that if $u$ follows the distribution given by density $(2)$, then the mapping defined by equation $(1)$ generates a point $z$ that is uniformly distributed over the line $c(V_1,V_2,V_3)$? If the answer is yes, can we consider my derivation of $p(y)$ as a valid proof of this fact?"
